# Функция перестаёт работать корректно внутри другой функции

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть задача, где необходимо написать бесконечный итератор по строке, т.е. нужно, чтобы после того, как элементы закончатся, выводились заново все элементы строки.
Я написал вот такое, и это, кажется, работает:

```
def do_stuff(s):
    i = 0
    while len(s) > 0:
        try:
            yield s[i]
            i += 1
        except IndexError:
            i = 0

foo = do_stuff('word')
```

Но проблема в том, что по условию задачи вывод должен осуществляться не через `next(foo)`, а просто через `foo()`.
Тогда я попытался сделать следующим образом:

```
def make_looper(s):
    def do_stuff():
        i = 0
        while len(s) > 0:
            try:
                yield s[i]
                i += 1
            except IndexError:
                i = 0
    return next(do_stuff())

foo = make_looper('word')
```

Но теперь возникает две проблемы:

1. `print(foo())`  выдаёт, что объект не `callable`. Что в принципе понятно, потому что `next(do_stuff())` - строка.
2. `print(foo)`  всё время выводит на печать только первый элемент строки.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def make_looper(s):
    iterable = iter(s)

    def looper():
        nonlocal iterable
        # nonlocal нужно чтобы можно было перезаписать переменную iterable во внешней функции

        try:
            return next(iterable)
        except StopIteration:
            iterable = iter(s)
            return next(iterable)
    
    return looper


foo = make_looper('word')
print(foo())
print(foo())
print(foo())
print(foo())
print(foo())
print(foo())
print(foo())
print(foo())
print(foo())
```

Вывод:

```
w
o
r
d
w
o
r
d
w
```

Другой вариант:

```
def make_looper(s):
    i = -1

    def do_stuff():
        nonlocal i
        i += 1
        if i >= len(s):
            i = 0
        
        return s[i]

    return do_stuff
```

"Про"-версия с использованием функции `cycle` из `itertools`, которая возвращает итератор, который бесконечно повторяет элементы исходной последовательности (по сути делает то что у вас делала первоначальная версия функции `do_staff`):

```
from itertools import cycle


def make_looper(s):
    iterable = cycle(s)

    def looper():
        return next(iterable)
    
    return looper
```